# Slot Machine generator in python , two functions are'nt working ( def get_slot_,machine_spin , def print_slot_machine )

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import random
MIN_LINES = 1
MAX_LINES = 3
MAX_BET = 100
MIN_BET = 1

ROW = 3
COL = 3

symbol_count = {
    "A":2,
    "B":4,
    "C":6,
    "D": 8,
}

def get_slot_machine_spin(rows,cols,symbols):
    all_symbols = []
    for symbol , symbol_count in symbols.items():
        for _ in range(symbol_count):
            all_symbols.append(symbol)
    columns = [[],[],[]]
    for _ in range(cols):
        current_symbols = all_symbols[:]
        for _ in range(rows):
            value = random.choice(current_symbols)
            current_symbols.remove(value)
            columns.append(value)
        columns.append(columns)
    return columns

def print_slot_machine(colmuns):
    for row in range(len(colmuns[0])):
        for i , colmun in enumerate(colmuns):
            if i != len(colmun) - 1:
                print(colmun[row], end="|")
            else:
                print(colmun[row], end="")
        print()
def deposit():
    amount = input("inter the amount of deposit you'd like to add ")
    if amount.isdigit():
        amount = int(amount)
        while amount > 0:
            break
        else: print("amount must be more than 0")
    else: print("Please enter a number ")
    return amount

def get_number_of_lines():
    lines = input("inter the amount of lines you'd like to add ")
    if lines.isdigit():
        lines = int(lines)
        while MIN_LINES <= lines <= MAX_LINES:
            break
        else: print("amount must be between 1~3")
    else: print("Please enter a number ")
    return lines


def get_bet():
    while True:
        amount = input("Inter the amount of deposit you'd like to bet \n")
        if amount.isdigit():
            amount = int(amount)
            while MIN_BET <= amount <= MAX_BET:
                break
            else:
                print(f"The amount must be between ${MIN_BET}and ${MAX_BET}\n ")
        else:
            print("Please enter a number ")
        return amount

def main():
    balance = deposit()
    lines = get_number_of_lines()
    while True:
        bet = get_bet()
        total_bet = bet *lines
        if total_bet> balance:
            print(f"you dont have enough to bet on that amount , your current balance is {balance}")
        else:
            break
    print(f"you're betting {bet},on {lines} lines . total bet is = ${total_bet}")
    slots = get_slot_machine_spin(ROW, COL,symbol_count)
    print_slot_machine(slots)
main()
```

I tried changing the two lines in many different ways but it didnt work plz help

```
slots = get_slot_machine_spin(ROW, COL,symbol_count)
    print_slot_machine(slots)
```

i got this code from a utube video called (Learn Python With This ONE Project!) i wrote the same code as but when he excute the code it shows him the Slot machine results ( abcd ) while am not getting it , i hope my question was clear ,,, all i want is to make the functions work and show the results of the random choices

Answer (score 1):

Your problems are all in the `get_slot_machine_spin` function.  Did you ever do a basic debug print of what it returns?  You would have immediately seen that it was wrong.

Look at what you're asking.  You're creating `columns` with three empty lists.  You then generate a random thing and add it to THAT list,  So, after three runs, you'd have `[[], [], [], 'A', 'C', 'D']`.  Then you append THAT list to ITSELF, and repeat.  When you see something like `columns.append(columns)`, that's an immediate indication that something is wrong.

You need to create a separate list to hold the individual column values, then you append that list to your master column list, which should start out empty.  Like this:

```
def get_slot_machine_spin(rows,cols,symbols):
    all_symbols = []
    for symbol , symbol_count in symbols.items():
        for _ in range(symbol_count):
            all_symbols.append(symbol)
    columns = []
    for _ in range(cols):
        row = []
        current_symbols = all_symbols[:]
        for _ in range(rows):
            value = random.choice(current_symbols)
            current_symbols.remove(value)
            row.append(value)
        columns.append(row)
    print(columns)
    return columns
```